# TemplateSelector.SelectTemplate don't trigger on PropertyChange

Tags: wpf, templates, binding

I have some data, which could be visualized by different reports. Each report has different properties ...
I created a dialog with a ComboBox to select the report and a ContentControl to show the editing controls dependant an the report type.

Dialog xaml looks like

```
<StackPanel Margin="9">
    <ComboBox Name="cbReport" IsEditable="False"
              VerticalAlignment="Center"
              ItemsSource="{Binding ReportTypes}"
              SelectionChanged="OnReportTypeChanged"
              SelectedValue="{Binding SelectedReportType, Mode=TwoWay}"
              SelectedValuePath="Content"
              DisplayMemberPath="Name"/>
    <ContentControl ContentTemplateSelector="{StaticResource DialogTemplateSelector}"
                    Content="{Binding CurStatistics}"/>
    <WrapPanel HorizontalAlignment="Right" Margin="0,9,0,0">
        <Button Name="pbDialogOK" Click="OnDialogOK" MinWidth="60" Margin="0,0,9,0"
                IsDefault="True">Ok</Button>
        <Button Name="pbDialogCancel" IsCancel="True" MinWidth="60">Cancel</Button>
    </WrapPanel>
</StackPanel>
```

Code behind routes the Combobox-event-callback to the ViewModel:

```
public partial class ReportDialog : Window
{
    private void OnReportTypeChanged(object sender, SelectionChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        ((DialogViewModel)DataContext).ChangeReportType((CBItem)e.AddedItems[0]);
    }
}
```

The ViewModel looks like:

```
public class DialogViewModel : ObservableObject
{
    //Statistics is an ObservableObject
    public Statistics CurStatistics { get; set; }
    public ObservableCollection<CBItem> ReportTypes { get; }
    public CBItem SelectedReportType {
        get => curReportType;
        set => SetProperty(ref curReportType, value);
    }
    CBItem curReportType;


    public void ChangeReportType(CBItem rt)
    {
        SelectedReportType = rt;
        //vomits PropertyChange event
        CurStatistics.ReportType = (ReportType)rt.Id;
    }
}
```

As mentioned in the code comments, Statistics is an ObservableObject, which sends a PropertyChange-event on setting ReportType member.

Setting breakpoint in ChangeReportType verifies, that ReportType is changed correctly.
But breakpoint in TemplateSelector.SelectTemplate triggers only at dialog creation and prooves, that template selections works as expected.

But on changing Combobox-Item ChangeReportType gets called, but SelectTemplate does not.

So what am I missing?

Answer (score 0):

> So what am I missing?

The statement

```
CurStatistics.ReportType = (ReportType)rt.Id;
```

does not change the value of the `CurStatistics` property and does hence not trigger the Binding

```
Content="{Binding CurStatistics}"
```

---

You may either assign a new value to the `CurStatistics` property (and make sure that it fires the PropertyChanged event) or perhaps use a MultiBinding on the Content property.